# Pan speed calculation to perform different tasks in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a set of objects in a UIScrollView that I am able to do the pan gesture. However, I would like to be able to scroll the view if i'm doing a swipe even if i hold the object and swipe too fast. Is it possible for me to calculate the speed of the drag and drop so i can make the UIScrollView move instead of executing a drag and drop of the swipe is fast?

What would be the solution for this? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way. You can ask a gesture recognizer to wait for another to fail before starting. It seems to me that it is what you want to achieve. Can you try :

```
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:myGestureRecognizer];
```

or the other way

```
[myGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: The pan would not exactly fail. The pan is working fine when moving the other object